# is iphone timezones reliable? Alternatives?

Tags: ios

I am currently writing an app that needs to represent some data arranged by local time. Since  I don't think relying on [NSDate date] is a good idea at all, because the user can change his time wrongly, hence messing up my data. I then thought it would be better to make a timestamp (server time) and then represent the data comparing the difference between my timestamp timezone and users timezone. Am I right doing it this way? 
Obviously this needs pretty much full reliance on timezones given by iOS are correct. If no, are there any better alternatives (like google timezone api?) (I would think they are both based on tz_database though?)

Thanks for any input

Comment: Haven't read any statistics about this, but based on my experience vast majority of the users leave it to be set automatically, hence being correct so altough it's not 100% flawless, you can rely on that relatively safely.

Comment: @skrew I guess Ill use a timestamp check to try an identify any variations if the user has set time wrong when travelling.